# VBScript slow byte array copy

Tags: javascript, vbscript, binary-data

I am using the following code to read in a binary file in VBScript and store it in a byte array which I then access from Javascript and copy to a JS array, basically just a sneaky way (the only way!) i've found of reading binary data in my JS.

```
Function readBinaryFile(fileName)
    dim inStream,buff

    set inStream=CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    inStream.Open
    inStream.type=1

    inStream.LoadFromFile fileName

    buff=inStream.Read()
    inStream.Close

    Dim byteArray()

    Dim i
    Dim len
    len = LenB(buff)

    ReDim byteArray(len)

    For i = 1 To len
        byteArray(i-1) = AscB(MidB(buff, i, 1))
    Next

    readBinaryFile=byteArray
End Function
```

It appears to work exactly as expected, the only problem being it seems extremely slow. For example, reading in a 300kb file can take over 2 minutes. I am expecting to read files up to around 2meg.

Could anyone explain why this is such a slow operation and if there's anything I can do to speed it up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not found a solution to this, but it's a side issue now and does work as it is (if very slowly in some circumstances) so not got time to look at it any further unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the loop. Try using disconnected recordset to do the conversion:

```
Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
    'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
    'RSBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
    'to a string (BSTR) using ADO recordset

    Dim Binary
    'MultiByte data must be converted To VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY first.
    If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

    Dim RS, LBinary
    Const adLongVarChar = 201
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    LBinary = LenB(Binary)

    If LBinary>0 Then
        RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
        RS.Open
        RS.AddNew
        RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary 
        RS.Update
        RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
    Else  
        RSBinaryToString = ""
    End If
End Function

Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
    '© 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
    ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
    ' Using recordset
    Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
    Const adLongVarBinary = 205
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
    If LMultiByte>0 Then
        RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
        RS.Open
        RS.AddNew
        RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
        RS.Update
        Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
    End If
    MultiByteToBinary = Binary
End Function
```

In your case have `readBinaryFile` return the "ASCII contents" of the file and use it instead of the array: `readBinaryFile = RSBinaryToString(buf)`

Comment: I think you're right that the problem is definitely having to loop through every byte and that's what I want to have to avoid, the above sounds worth a try but i'm not sure if it'll do what I need. I need to access the raw bytes so i can move through them a byte at a time recreating 4 byte integers and various other types. I'm not sure I can do what I need with an ASCII string.

Comment: @Adam: try reading the ASCII values of the returned string, they might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think its because you are using a high level scripting language to emulate something that should be done by low-level compiled languages.  I guess there's a reason scripts don't support binary data.  They are not designed to deal with data one byte at a time.  Looping through 300,000 bytes of data would take a noticable amount of time in many languages, but a non-compiled (scripting) language makes it even worse.  The only things I can suggest are using a compiled language instead, or using some ActiveX object created in a compiled language that supports the operations you want to perform without having to perform them byte-by-byte in script.  Do you have the option of using compiled components or other languages?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have a choice here, this is a purely web based application and I don't have the ability to use any further plugins or compiled components.

Comment: For Firefox users we do have a plugin that does this operation with no problems, the issue is IE users.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of embedding .NET components on the page? I know .NET has mechanism to embed components on a page that run sandboxed similar to Java (I would guess) but I haven't played around with them much.  Of course, I suppose Java itself would be better too and probably more portable. Are you not even able to use those sorts of components?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean but we are already using XBAP's embedded in the page, these are web-based .NET WPF applications and are quite powerful but really not lightweight enough for the operation we're trying to do here.

Comment: I think I'm talking more about something directly in the web page that the script can talk to. .NET controls... see this example: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030610.htm